# Hi is there a way to use 2 different variable files within same task in ansible?

Tags: ansible

This is playbook that creates users.I want to create user(that takes username and uid) accoording to userlist.yml but passwords will be taken in passwords.yml. But don't know exact syntax

```
- name: add users
  hosts: new
  vars_files:
    - userlist.yml
    - passwords.yml
  tasks:
    - name: adduser
      user:
        name: "{{ item.username }}"
        password: "{{ item.password  | password_hash('sha512') }}"
        uid: "{{item.uid}}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        ?????????????
```

---

```
#userlist.yml
users:
   - username: xman
     uid: 8254
   - username: yman
     uid: 8252
   - username: zman
     uid: 8258
```

---

```
#passwords.yml
  password: devops2019!
```

Answer (score 0):

Given *"**passwords** will be taken in passwords.yml"*. For example

```
#passwords.yml
password:
  - 'devops2019!'
  - 'devops2020!'
  - 'devops2021!'
```

The task below does the job

```
- name: adduser
  user:
    name: "{{ item.0.username }}"
    password: "{{ item.1 | password_hash('sha512') }}"
    uid: "{{ item.0.uid }}"
    state: present
  loop: "{{ users | zip(password) | list }}"
```

(not tested)